# Was only Death Note Box Set 2 reprinted?

Tags: death-note, merchandise

**This is for the anime**

I see that Volume 2 has been going out of stock everywhere - but it seems like it got a reprint this year. Was only Volume 2 actually reprinted? Is there no Volume 1 reprint?

I can't find any information about this on the internet.

Comment: Is this really a good question?

Comment: @user1306322 I don't see why not. It's about anime -- and it's very objective. There can only be one answer. Could you explain why you think it's not?

Comment: It's about merchandise to be exact, which happens to be of anime. I guess you could ask about why there was a second batch of CE of some series on TV and Movies to the same effect. It's a medium's merch department's decision, which is dictated by market, so there shouldn't be much to it, and it doesn't seem to be tied closely enough to its contents.

Comment: I think you're missing the question. This is specifically as to asking if a reprint of VOLUME ONE was reprinted. Since it seemed there's plans to reprint it but they started on the last half...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by [Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/Death-Note-Volume-Box-Set/dp/B001R8B5TO), Box Set 2 is reprinted. However, [Box Set 1](http://www.amazon.ca/Death-Note-1-Box-Set/dp/B001CZJP0S/ref=sr_1_1?s=dvd&ie=UTF8&qid=1418199871&sr=1-1&keywords=Death%20Note%20Box%20Set%201) has not been. In fact, Box Set 2 isn't "reprinted" persay as the new edition with a different cover art was released.

That's case closed on this one.